# How to convert arraylist to array?

Tags: android, linkedhashmap, copyonwritearraylist

I have an arraylist with JSON values. I want to convert it to an array, then I will send it to MapActivity.  I tried a lot of ways but I failed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) 
{
    JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
    String matchId = c.getString(TAG_MATCHID);
    Log.d("matchId", matchId);

    //  hashmap for single match
    HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    matchFixture.put(TAG_MATCHID, matchId);

    matchFixtureList.add(matchFixture);

    //item=matchFixtureList.get(0).toString();
    String[] stockArr = matchFixtureList.toArray(new String[matchFixtureList.size()]);
    stockArr = matchFixtureList.toArray(stockArr);
    for(String s : stockArr)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `stockArr = matchFixtureList.toArray(stockArr);` that is happening in the `toArray` call above it.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to typecast a `HashMap` to a `String`
Your map is -

```
 //  hashmap for single match
    HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    matchFixture.put(TAG_MATCHID, matchId);
```

And you are adding `matchFixture` (which is a map) to an `ArrayList` (which should be a list of HashMaps)

```
matchFixtureList.add(matchFixture);
```

Now if you want to convert `matchFixtureList` to an array then you  should do like this -

```
    HashMap<String,String>[] stockArr = new HashMap[matchFixtureList.size()];
    stockArr = matchFixtureList.toArray(stockArr);
    for(HashMap<String,String> map : stockArr)
       for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()){
           Log.d("debug", entry.getKey() + ","+ entry.getValue());
       }
```

Comment: can i send these values to Mapaciticity these are basically latitudes

Comment: You can do whatever you want to do with these values.

Comment: sir i want to send these values as simple array that i can put as longitude and latitude . . is it possible

Comment: How can you mix lat and long into one single array? That doesn't sounds good. You can pass complete ArrayList instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change following lines

```
String[] stockArr = matchFixtureList.toArray(new String[matchFixtureList.size()]);
stockArr = matchFixtureList.toArray(stockArr);
```

to

```
String[] stockArr = new String[matchFixtureList.size()];
stockArr = matchFixtureList.toArray(stockArr);
```

The error was that you were doing a conversion to array during initialization of array which is not needed at all.